# Core Data: NSCocoaErrorDomain=134040 Only Occurs On Real Phone, Not Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data

I'm using Core Data to save a persistent store in the document directory of my application. When I attempt to save my managed context changes, I get a Cocoa Error 134040. This only occurs on the real iPhone in debug mode, not on the simulator. Any idea why this occurs?

This is how I initially create my data store in the documents directory.

```
    NSString *documentDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                     NSUserDomainMask,
                                                                     YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSURL *userDataStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentDirPath
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userdata.coredata"]];
    userDataStore= [persistentStoreCoordinator_ addPersistentStoreWithType:NSBinaryStoreType
        configuration:@"UserData"
        URL:userDataStoreURL
        options:nil
        error:&error];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    # The following IF statement never executes, so I know the file is being created.
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[userDataStoreURL path]]) {
        NSLog(@"User data file does not exist: %@", [userDataStoreURL path]);
    }
```

This is how I save the context:

```
[managedObjectContext_ save:&error];
```

This is the error I get when trying to save the managed object context:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134040 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134040.)" UserInfo=0x607b80 {NSAffectedStoresErrorKey=(
    "<NSBinaryObjectStore: 0x23f870>",
        (
        "<NSBinaryObjectStore: 0x23f870>"
    )
), NSUnderlyingException=Save partially failed: Directory does not exist or is not writable /var/mobile/Applications/...[app bundle path]}
```

**MORE CLARIFICATION**

I actually have 2 persistent stores. One is suppose to be read only data that doesn't change in between upgrades and it resides in the main bundle. The other is a data store for things saved by the user, and this resides inside the Document folder. Both persistent stores belong to the same managed object context, but I use configurations to only save certain entities to each (i.e. read only entities go in one, user saved entities goes in another).

```
NSPersistentStore *readonlyStore = [persistentStoreCoordinator_
  addPersistentStoreWithType:NSBinaryStoreType
  configuration:@"ReadOnlyData"
  URL:readonlyStoreURL
  options:nil
  error:&error];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get an error, look it up. This one is in CoreDataErrors.h (there are also FoundationErrors.h and a few others):

```
    NSPersistentStoreIncompleteSaveError             = 134040, // one or more of the stores returned an error during save (stores/objects that failed will be in userInfo)
```

So, you couldn't save, and the userInfo tells you why.

Indeed it does. From your question:

```
NSUnderlyingException=Save partially failed: Directory does not exist or is not writable /var/mobile/Applications/...[app bundle path]}
```

You're trying to save into your app bundle. That won't work; your app bundle is not writable (certainly not on the device).

You showed the creation of a persistent store in the documents directory. As far as I can tell by reading it, that should be working. Do you have any other persistent stores, perhaps that you intended to default to the contents of/migrate from? If so, please edit your question to include that code.

Comment: Yes Peter, I do have multiple stores. I added more clarification in the question.

Comment: You can't create a persistent store that references a file in your app bundle, because there's no way to specify that the store is read-only. One way to do this might be to create an in-memory store and migrate the on-disk store into it. Alternatively (and probably preferably), store your read-only data somewhere else.

Comment: Actually, I've been doing that with my current app version. It's currently ONLY read-only and works fine in the main bundle. Now I'm introducing a 2nd store for user savable data in the documents folder. I think I may have to go the route of moving both stores to the documents folder. I can't figure out why Core Data might be writing to the read only store in the main bundle since none of the entities in that store are being updated (using Data Model configurations to achieve this).

Comment: Okay, I moved the read only store to the document directory and it fixed the issue. Not sure why it was trying to open the read only store for writing. I analyzed the read only datastore using an MD5 sum before and after making changes to the user datastore and it didn't change at all. It would be nice if Core data added the ability to designate stores as readonly.

Comment: @pokstad: The result of your MD5 comparison should not surprise you: The file is not writable (because it's part of your app bundle), which means that it is impossible to change it at all, by any means. The only thing that can do anything to it is the OS, when uninstalling your app.

Comment: Actually, I meant to say that I attempted this on OS X as a console app where I was able to write to that directory. Even though it had the proper privileges to modify the file, it still didn't modify it.