# Testing Core Data on iPhone without connection to Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Running the App on the iPhone works fine, but only if it stays connected to the Mac/linked to Xcode.
If I try to run it after I disconnected it (after stopping the Run), Core Data does not work anymore. Neither the *Build* nor the *Debug* configuration works (Product -> Edit scheme... -> Run xy.app -> Info -> Build configuration).
My xcdatamodel settings:
File Type: Default Core Data Model
Location: Relative to Group

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Saeppi

---

Sorry for not being more specific about my issue. There's no crash, the changes I thought I did to the Core Data Model just did not happen.
Reading a bit more about SQLite and how it works with Core Data, I admit that I committed a very stupid error: I copied the *.sqlite file from a tutorial and imported it into my Xcode project and copied it to the App's folder (and then renaming it of course). Removing the sqlite file causes now the following error:

> *error: /Users/myName/Documents/myApp/myApp.sqlite: No such file or directory*

My PersistentStoreCoordinator:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"MyApp.sqlite"]];

NSError *error = nil;
persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ErrorKey", nil)
                                                    message:NSLocalizedString(@"ErrorDBKey", nil)
                                                   delegate:nil   
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"   
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];   
    [alert show];   
    [alert release];   
}    
return persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

}

and my application's directory:

```
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

I thought Core Data would generate a new sqlite file once it's been removed from the folder. What's the error in reasoning?

Comment: can u explain something more on the same?

Comment: *"Doesn't work"* is an extremely unhelpful description.  What happens?  Does it crash?  Give results that you weren't expecting?  Fail to run altogether?

Comment: How can you be sure it is Core Data that is the problem? You really need to give us more details or we cannot possible help you.

Answer (score 0):

Does it crash on device?
You can connect the device and check the crash report in device logs.It will give you better idea about what is happening.Secondly try to quit app from background and run.

I would suggest check the crash logs on device, if it's not able to create or find the core data it will give a message like: store missing or something like that.

Comment: There's no crash, hence no crash log. What do you mean by "quit the app from background"?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are opening your db file in the main bundle.  Main bundle is read only.  Your db file needed to be in the app's document folder.

Checkout this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141333/core-data-nscocoaerrordomain-134040-only-occurs-on-real-phone-not-simulator)

Comment: No, according to the sandbox, the sqlite file is in the Documents folder. Any other ideas?